# Is there any difference beetween cloned div and a div created in loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any difference between a div cloned and a div generated in a loop ? 
I have two situations: 
div 1 :

```
$('.div1').clone(true).insertAfter('.created_form');
```

div 2 : 
loop

```
<div class="div2"></div>
```

endloop

I have a button in each div, to delete the div when the button is pressed. 
But the button for delete work only for the cloned div (div1).
For div 2 is not working. 
My code for deleting the div is :

```
$('.buttons').on('click', '.minus_sign', function() {
        var parent_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $("#"+parent_id).remove();
        $("input[name='"+parent_id+"']").remove();              
    });
```

Can someone tell me why this is not working for both  please ? I mention that the div is exaclty the same, only the id is different! Thank you

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to say what the problem is. Post a complete example, please.

Comment: Can you show a more complete code snippet that includes the ids? The implication of what is happening is that your loop-generated div does not have an id set.

Comment: Hi,
jQuery .clone() copy the event listeners of your element, so i suppose that your loop is executed after your listener declaration. Am I right?

Comment: the problem was with the action event. Instead of .on i put .live and now it's working.

Comment: `.live()` is just a shortcut to `.on()` (and removed in newer versions of jQuery), so it was just a matter of wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the one created without the clone doesn't have an `id` attribute.

```
<div class="div2"></div>
```

However, if you were give it an id:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="div2"></div>
```

it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the original element had an `id` attribute, the one you're creating inside the loop doesn't have an `id` attribute as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26118665/2333214).

Even if it has one, since you're using `.clone(true)`, the clone will have the data and event handlers of the cloned element.

But the one created inside loop does not contain the event handler.

And the event delegation will not work since you're delegating the click of `.minus_sign` to the button which is also dynamically created.

You should delegate the event handler to a static element, for example

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttons .minus_sign', function() {
    var parent_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $("#"+parent_id).remove();
    $("input[name='"+parent_id+"']").remove();              
});
```

BTW, Since `remove()` method returns the removed element, you can do the above like

```
 $(document).on('click', '.buttons .minus_sign', function() {
    var parent_id = $(this).parent().remove().attr('id');
    $("input[name='"+parent_id+"']").remove();              
});
```